# how to display wordpress posts by order "title"

Tags: php, wordpress

i used this function to get posts of category withe slug naruto_chapitre_005

```
$myposts = get_posts(array(
    'showposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array('naruto_chapitre_005'))
    ))
);



foreach ($myposts as $mypost) {
      echo $mypost->post_title . '<br/>';
}

//output
04
01
05
02
03
```

how to get the posts by order ? 
like this 
01 
02 
03 
04 
05

Comment: `showposts` is depreciated. Use `posts_per_page`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `orderby` attribute with the value `title`:

```
   $myposts = get_posts(array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'order'     => 'ASC',
            'orderby'   => 'title',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array('naruto_chapitre_005'))
            ))
        );
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**

```
$myposts = get_posts(array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'order'     => 'ASC',
        'orderby'   => 'title',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array('naruto_chapitre_005'))
        ))
    );
```